# Access passed array element in ejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, element, ejs

I am testing the following code which uses an array passed from my node.js script to an .ejs file.  I seem to have a problem accessing the individual array elements in a loop.  Other than that the other array methods seem functional, for example the .length seems to return a proper value.  The error indicates to be unable to access the array element index position.  The error message is "_count is not defined"...what am I doing wrong here?

My node.js:

```
var test_up = [{pix: "Post 1", name: "Nica"}, {pix: "Post 2", name: "Danielle"}, {pix: "Post 3", name: "Maricar"}, {pix: "Post 4", name: "Peter"}, {pix: "Post 5", name: "Sampson"}, {pix: "Post 6", name: "Cleo"}]; 
res.render('index_bootx', {test_list: test_up});
```

Javascript in EJS file with the code causing the problem:

```
function initialize() {

var _count = 0;
var _limits = <%= test_list.length %>;  //THIS SEEMS FUNCTIONAL...
var _tally = 0;  

 if (<%= test_list.length %> > 20) {_limits = 20;}  //NO ERROR HERE...

  for (_count = 0; _count < _limits; _count++) {

  //**CREATE CONTENT HERE...

  var _item = document.createElement("div"); 
  _item.setAttribute("class", "lineups");
  _item.setAttribute("id", "member_" + _count);
  document.getElementById("row_" + _tally).appendChild(_item);

  var _name = document.createElement("h2");
  label = document.createTextNode(<% test_list[_count] %>);  //PROBLEM HERE! '_count is not defined'
  _name.appendChild(label);
  lineups.appendChild(_name);

 //**

 }  //for loop

}
```

What is the proper syntax to use for element selection in passed arrays to an .ejs file...?  I thank you in advance.

I have modified the end of my function to include a 'JSON.stringify' command, as so:

```
var test = <%- JSON.stringify(test_list) %>;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = test;
```

...but the result of the "demo" is simply a bunch of 'objects'...however the correct number:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Why am I seeing 'object' references here instead of the actual name strings after I apply the JSON.stringify method?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `<%` tags around the `for` loop also like this:

```
<% var _count; %>
<% for (_count = 0; _count < _limits; _count++) { %>
...
<% } %> // for loop
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that will solve the issue.  My function is running within a script tag ...not within the DOM itself.  I have been running various attempts to solve this problem, and I think I need to do some usage of the 'JSON.stringify' method...it seems to work without an error however the resulting array is simply filled with 'objects'...see my edited post.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok. I figured the variable declaration needed to be within ejs tags too for it to see _count as defined. I guess not.

Comment: Is it possible to use ANY Javascript within the DOM body as long as it is enclosed in <% %> tags...???   If so I might be able to re-write the function commands within the DOM...possibly....?

Comment: I got it finally...!  I was correct about the usage of the JSON.stringify command.  After doing that I am able to access the needed 'name' strings using "document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = test[_count].name;" where the '_count' is the index element of each item in the array.  I wish various tutorials and documentation were a little clearer about the need to convert the array objects into strings.  However I am happy this seems to be solved now.